# I'm trying to make PHPMailer work but it keeps giving me the SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

[image]So, I'm trying to make my main.php file send an email based on the @ I give on my html page and I keep getting the same error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. I know it's a pretty common error, but I've searched a lot of sites and the PHPMailer documentation itself trying to find a way to solve this issue but I couldn't find anything useful.

Here's my code on my .php file and my php.ini configuration about SMTP properties

```
try{
        $mail= new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
        $mail->IsSMTP();        
        $mail->SMTPDebug = false;       
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';            
        $mail->Port = 465; 
        $mail->Username = 'example1@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password = '4488abcd2266';
        $mail->SetFrom('t25307469@gmail.com');
        $mail->addAddress('example@gmail.com');
        $mail->Subject=("Assunto");
        $mail->msgHTML("Sua mensagem");
        
        if ($mail->send()){         
            $ok = true;
            echo 'it worked';
        }else{          
            $ok = false;
            echo 'didn't work';
        }
```

Comment: You can't `setFrom` when using Gmail SMTP; they'll ignore it. You'll also need to be using an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) rather than the account's main password. In general, you want something else for sending automated emails; Mailgun, SendGrid, AWS SES, etc.

Comment: You don't show any evidence of having tried [what the troubleshooting guide suggests](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps).

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting, "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate" is likely due to PHPMailer not being able to authenticate with the SMTP server. This could be due to several reasons, including incorrect SMTP credentials/ SMTP server settings.

Try:

- Double-check that your Google credentials are correct (especially the
  16-character code generated from your Google account).
- Set the $mail->SMTPDebug property to SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER so as to enable SMTP debug mode. That way you will get more details about the error.
- Carefully verify that the SMTP server settings you are using are correct

### update: 06-05-2023

1. log in to your Gmail account
2. Go to the Security setting and Enable 2-factor authentication And
   then, from the 'Your app passwords' tab select the Other option and
   put your app name (For the Laragon mailer I typed Laragon)
3. Click GENERATE button to get a new app password.
   Finally copy the 16-digit password and click done. Save it
   somewhere.
4. Open the app you want to send email from. Now use this password
   instead of the Gmail password to send mail via your app. In my case, I am using this Gmail account on 3 different installations (Laragon) so I use the same App password, email address remains the same.

I have reinstalled Laragon and used the same app password and it keeps working. With 'less secure apps', Google used to turn the feature off after a few uses.

Comment: the 16-characters code is used instead of the password of the account? I saw a video of a guy saying that it replaces the account password, but then I read somewhere that this kind of service was cancelled by Google last year, so I basically ignored it. Can you tell me more about how should I use the key?

Comment: I have added more details for you. I hope you sort out the problem.